# Hibernate rename Check Constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have searched but not got a answer for this, so there are way to rename a check constraint in Hibernate? My Hibernate version is 3.6.10 and JPA: jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final

```
@Entity
@Check(constraints="categoria_for>0 and categoria_for<=5")
public class Fornecedor implements Serializable{
//...
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hy @JoaoMosquito, I'm trying rename the default check constraint name, because Hibernate put strange name, something like that: SYS_C0027401